# Unable to display Month in widget Android 5.1

Tags: android, date

I use TextClock command in a home widget. No problem in KitKat but in Lollipop I don't found a way to display the month.
I usually use MMM or MMMMM but in lollipop the result is something like this: 01/10/2015.

Why? Any idea?
Thanks

this is my code:

```
                           <TextClock
                           android:id="@+id/secondi"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                           android:layout_alignTop="@+id/analogClock1"
                           android:layout_marginRight="96dp"
                           android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
                           android:format12Hour="EEE, dd MMMM"
                           android:format24Hour="EEE, dd MMMM"
                           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                           android:lines="2"
                           android:textColor="#e6e6e6"
                           android:textSize="11dp"
                           android:typeface="sans"
                           android:width="45dp" />
```

The same widget in a Kitkat phone display: "Thu, 01 October" in another lollipop phone "10/1/2015

Comment: Could you post your code and a screenshot

Comment: Thanks Waclock, the code is in the post.